# jquery on click not working for dynamically added items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding some code(!with js code included!) dynamically.

```
<div class="r"></div>
<script>
    //Here is code that dinamiccaly add another div into div.r
    //Example:
    //<div class="w"><img src="a.png"><div class="i">Some Text</div></div>
    $('.r').on('click', $('.w'), function (e) {
        console.log($(this).children($('.i')).text());
    });
</script>
```

Problem that this click event works anythere I click in div.w and returns text of ALL div.w combined in one string without spaces (sometext1sometext2).

Sorry if I wrote something wrong. I'm bad in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event delegation is wrong. You are using a jQuery collection

```
$('.r').on('click', $('.w'), function (e) {
                    ^^^^^^^
```

where it should be just a selector

```
$('.r').on('click', '.w', function (e) {
                    ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector has to be of type `string`. Look at the following:

```
$('.r').on('click', '.w', function (e) {
```

from [documentation of on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)